# Webgl FrameBuffer depth buffer is not clearing

Tags: javascript, typescript, webgl

I'm making a 2D sprite renderer, where the sprites draw to a render texture to allow for custom compositing. The issue is that for some reason the depth buffer on the FrameBuffer is not clearing, causing all the sprite to erase a permanent "streak," across all the tiles that are behind them. Basically the same thing that happens when you forget to clear a color buffer, just instead of color the tiles in front streak like an eraser.

Setup code for frame buffer object

```
constructor(gl: WebGL2RenderingContext, width: number, height: number, depthBuffer = false){
    this._gl = gl;
    this._texture = this._gl.createTexture()!;
    this._frameBuffer = this._gl.createFramebuffer()!;

    this._gl.bindTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._texture);
    this._gl.bindFramebuffer(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this._frameBuffer);
    this._gl.framebufferTexture2D(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this._gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._texture, 0);

    this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this._gl.LINEAR);
    this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this._gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this._gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    if (depthBuffer){
        console.log("This logs out, so I know it gets created")
        this._depthBuffer = this._gl.createRenderbuffer();
        this._gl.bindRenderbuffer(this._gl.RENDERBUFFER, this._depthBuffer);
        this._gl.renderbufferStorage(this._gl.RENDERBUFFER, this._gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
        this._gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this._gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, this._gl.RENDERBUFFER, this._depthBuffer);
    }

    this._gl.bindFramebuffer(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}
setAsRenderTarget(): void {
    this._gl.bindFramebuffer(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this._frameBuffer);
}

unsetRenderTarget(): void {
    this._gl.bindFramebuffer(this._gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}
```

And here's the render code

```
render(): void {
    this._gl.useProgram(this._program);
    this._outputTexture.setAsRenderTarget();
    
    this._gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    this._gl.clear(this._gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this._gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    this._gl.enable(this._gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    this._gl.depthFunc(this._gl.LEQUAL);
    this._gl.depthMask(true);

    //render each atlas as a draw call
    for (let i = 0; i < this._atlasPool.length; i++){
        //gets atlas buffer and draws instanced arrays
        //no depth/frame/render buffer related code
    }

    this._gl.disable(this._gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    this._gl.depthMask(false);

    this._outputTexture.unsetRenderTarget();
}
```

I know it's a depth buffer clearing issue, because if I resize the depth buffer before rendering (which basically creates a new depth buffer every frame) then everything seems to work perfectly, but obviously I don't want to be doing that.

It looks like the buffer *should* be clearing, so is there anything that stands out that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out I just had to make sure I set `this._gl.depthMask(true)` *before* I clear the buffer